# Multiple password Protect Php for a single user

Tags: php

I have literally done extensive research on the above topic and it's since been futile. The only available results i have been able to get is specifying arrays of password in cases where you have variety of users, so that if they enter any of the password in the arrays, they are granted access to the protected content. I have also come across using a single password to protect a file.

But what I need to complete the project am working on is PROTECTING A PHP PAGE from a single user using four different passwords, i.e when the user inputs the first password, it requests for the second which inturns request for the third and the third requests for the fourth before access is granted to the required content.

Thanks in anticipation.
Am new to php.

To be more specific, i have this below line of code which protects the page or content with a single password

```
<?php 
$password = "ABACLB102"; // Modify Password to suit for access, Max 10 Char. ?>
 <?php 
// If password is valid let the user get access
if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password")) {
?>
Hidden Content
Hidden Content goes here
<?php 
}
else
{
// Wrong password or no password entered display this message
if (isset($_POST['password']) || $password == "") {
  print "<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\"><b>Incorrect Code entered</b><br>Please enter the correct code or contact Administrator</font></p>";}
  print "<form method=\"post\"><p align=\"center\"><h2>Please enter code to intiate transfer</h2><br>";
  print "<input name=\"password\" type=\"password\" size=\"25\" maxlength=\"10\"><input value=\"Authenticate\" type=\"submit\"></p></form>";
}
?>
```

But i need to protect the page with Four different password, so if the user enters the first one, it requests for another till all four are enter before hidden content is displayed.

Comment: Why not just use nested `if` conditionals? `if ($password1) { ... show prompt for password2 ... if ($password2) { ... } }` etc.

Comment: what research? seems trivial, what's the *specific* problem?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for your prompt response but am confused as i am new to php, please look at the post edit and assist me with what i am supposed to do using if conditionals.

Comment: This is a pretty weird requirement, which is often a sign you're doing something that really doesn't need to be done. That said, consider using PHP's sessions to store whether they've answered each of the four passwords. **That** said, we're not going to just write the code for you.

Comment: @ceejayoz, if there's any tutorial online that I could follow, can you please point me to it? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Aliu, are you familiar with session?

Comment: Yes but no like a pro @micheal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, user has to enter 4 different passwords, so you can use session to remember each stage like followings:

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = false;
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

    $stage = (isset($_SESSION['stage']))? $_SESSION['stage'] : 0;
    $stage_labels = array(
        'First',
        'Second',
        'Third',
        'Final'
    );

    $passwords = array(
        '111',
        '222',
        '333',
        '444'
    );

    if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == $passwords[$stage]) {

        if ($stage == 3) {
            // if the final password matches, create a session variable for login
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'loggedin';
            header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            exit();
        } else {
            // if password matches the respective stage, increase the value of stage by 1 to move on to next stage
            $_SESSION['stage'] = $stage + 1;
            header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            exit();
        }

    } elseif (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = true;
        // if form submitted with mismatch password, stage will restart from 0 again
        print '<p align="center"><font color="red"><b>Incorrect Code entered</b><br>Please enter the correct code or contact Administrator</font></p>';
        $_SESSION['stage'] = 0;

    }

    if (!$error) {
        print '<p>Please enter your '. $stage_labels[$stage].' password</p>';
    }

    print '<form method="post"><p align="center"><h2>Please enter code to intiate transfer</h2><br>';
    print '<input name="password" type="password" maxlength="10"><input value="Authenticate" type="submit"></p></form>';

} else {
    echo 'You have logged in';
}
?>
```

Comment: @Micheal, This worked Perfectly, i used meta http-equiv="refresh" to redirect them to the protected page... Is there a way to clear the cookie immidiately after the redirection?

Comment: What cookie? which cookie? If you want to unset a session, do that before redirecting otherwise it won't be immediately reflected as page is already rendered